# bigsqcup with sideset doesn't shrink in subscript

Tags: math-mode

I'm using a `\bigsqcup` that involves a `\sideset` inside a subscript for a function, but the `\bigsqcup` symbol doesn't get smaller like everything else.  Is there a way to make it shrink proportionally with the other symbols while using `\sideset`?

Here's a self contained example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \bigsqcup_{\sideset{}{_B}\bigsqcup V} A
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

It displays like this:
[image: sideset problem]

Comment: I think this question may be illformed.  This may be a consequence of the environment that I'm using.  This is inside a mathpar from the mathpartir package and there is a sideset in affect on the \bigsqcup.  I'm still investigating.

Comment: Apparently this has something to do with \sideset.

Comment: I get two different sizes with: `\bigsqcup  A_{\bigsqcup}`.  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the new insights from your comments. Also add the exact code of the formula.

Comment: Exact code is too complex.  Way too many macros.  I've added a distilled version.  It is definitely `sideset` related, so the question is updated with that information.

Comment: Is what you are trying to achieve the same as `\bigsqcup_{\bigsqcup_B V} A`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point is that `\sideset` just isn't designed to be used in sub- and superscripts: it issues an explicit `\displaystyle` in which the big operator will be typeset. In your case, you can just use `\bigsqcup_B V` in the subscript, as Peter suggests in his comment. The `B` is set at the side since it's in a subscript. (In other cases, you can use `\bigsqcup\nolimits_B V`.)

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \bigsqcup_{\bigsqcup_B V} A
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```